# Ubuntu Software report google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb is unsafe in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: google-chrome

My Chrome says it can't be updated and I need to reinstall it.

Problem Environment: Chrome Version 101.0.4951.64 (Official Build) (64-bit) on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS - jammy

[image: Can't upgrade Chrome, you must reinstall]

Then I downloaded the 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb' file from the 'Reinstall Chrome' button directly from the browser window itself where it tells me that I can NOT update the browser.

When I wanted to install via 'Ubuntu Software' it appeared:

[image]

I find it's hard to believe that a '.deb' file generated from Google is reported as 'insecure'

Can I ignore the message and install it anyway?

Should I download the .deb file from another source?

what would be the correct procedure?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me...

Gustavo. (Argentina)

P.D.: Sorry for my English, it is not my natural language

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I decided:

1. uninstall the browser with the command:

sudo apt install google-chrome-stable

2. using firefox I downloaded again the file 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb' from the URL:
   https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/chrome/
3. I installed this time ignoring the warning message and then the browser worked well in the most stable version.

Hope this helps someone in the same situation.

Gustavo